# TypeError: undefined is not an object(evaluation'_this.props.navigation.openDrawer')

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new to programming and I am going through some problems I can't fix. I hope some of you can help.

I'm getting the error message:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object(evaluation'_this.props.navigation.openDrawer')

as I am trying to click on my navigator. I want to navigate from my Profile view to Booking View.

Comment: Next to your error message you should see the line number from where the problem comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your app and I just had the login page with no drawer so it seems that the second render() method of your App class overrides the first one.

Then I deleted the second render() method on App.js

Then I tested again your source code : the drawer works fine on Android, iO, chrome and Firefox, it opens whenever the user clicks on the forwardburger icon.

**So I bet that your issue is having two render() methods.**

If not, here are the steps that led me to make your project work in isolation :

```
expo init
```

-> on interactive questions of expo init, I set the name to « openDrawer_problem » then the template to « blank »

```
expo install firebase
expo install expo-constants
expo install react-navigation
expo install react-navigation-drawer
expo install @expo/vecto-icons
expo install react-native-paper
expo install react-native-screens
expo install react-native-gesture-handler
expo install react-native-reanimated
expo start
```

Side notes on your question :

- CRITICAL - You have two render() methods in App.js !! The second overrides the first.
- WONDERING - You exposed your firebase access on the internet. could it be misused ? I don't know anything about firebase, it just puzzled me.
- FYI - Your code misses the dependency "./components/LoginForm » and "./components/SignUpForm". It would be nice to get it working out of the box.I had to mock them.
- IMPORTANT - Unles you get a valid reason, your file extensions would better all be standard (lowercase, i.e. .js ). Apparently, .Js extensions are not recognized by the module loader. I had to replace .Js -> .js

Let me know if this solves your problem, I am curious ;)